# How to show a User Control after loading all its controls?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, user-controls

I have a panel in a WinForm application, is used to display a User Control. The code is this:

```
Public Sub AddUserControlsToPanel(us As UserControl)
    pn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    pnContainer.Controls.Clear()
    pnContainer.Controls.Add(pn)
End Sub
```

This code works perfectly but while the User control is dispalying on the panel, I can see that it  renders too slow. I have also some User Controls with a `DataGridView` or a `ListView` that display data from the data base, on those cases, the User control takes between 5 to 10 sec to render completly.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFNN4.gif) is what happends when I load a User Control with `Textbox`es, `Button`s and `Lable`s and in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVOj6.gif) case (`ListView`, the same happends on a `DataGridView`) takes time to load and it's not in it position when displayng.

What can I do to display it faster? or How can I display it after loading all its control?

Comment: Hi, are you sure that the problem is caused by the UC ? If you do the same work directly in a form, it is faster ?

Comment: There is not an U. Control issue, seems you have a big amount of data in your `DataGridView`. If so,to avoid those delays is convenient to use its `Property` called `VirtualMode`. Take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-4.0

Comment: Hi @UserNam3, yeah, it's caused by the UC because at the moment when I add a UC to  the panel with less controls, it does the same thing. It shows frist in a position and then in the center, so it take a couple sec to do it. I tried to do it directly in a form and it's the same. Do you have any advice of how I can display it faster?

Comment: How many elements are in the datagridview ? If the dgv have a lot of elements, this lag is normal.

Comment: @UserNam3 I added some gifs as links so you can see what I mean. Thanks for your help ^^.

Comment: Hi @UserNam3, it would be very helpful any advice, is there any way I could make it work like a loading page or something?

Comment: I dont have any idea, I know WPF is better for this kind of work but it's very different from winforms...

Comment: Hi @G3nt_M3caj sorry to bother you, do you know any way i can make like a loading page? I added some gifs so you can understand what I meant

Comment: @MyNameIsInYourHeart When you populate your grid you should use `YourGrid.SuspendLayout` then once you are sure all data is loaded you can turn on Layout with  `YourGrid.ResumeLayout`.However there is more other factors to analyze your scenario which needs to see entire code/structure of your app.